# I want to get the elements of the entire branch from the Reaitime database and output all the received data to the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an interface in which I transmit ArrayList.

```
public interface GetMinerFromBase{
    void GetMinerFromBase(ArrayList<Miner> minersFromBase);
}
```

Next, I get data from the Realtime Database using the interface.

I want to get the data of the entire branch and put it in an ArrayList.

```
public static void AllminersFromBase(FirebaseModel model, Callbacks.GetMinerFromBase callback) {
    model.initAll();
    Query query = model.getReference("AppData/AllMiners");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            ArrayList<Miner> minersFromBase=new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Miner miner = new Miner();
                miner.setInHour(snap.child("AllMiners").getValue(Long.class));
                miner.setMinerPrice(snap.child("AllMiners").getValue(Long.class));
                miner.setMinerImage(snap.child("AllMiners").getValue(Long.class));
                minersFromBase.add(miner);
            }
            callback.GetMinerFromBase(minersFromBase);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

[Here is a photo of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBg55.png)

Here is the method in which I get a variable from the previous method to add it to the RecyclerView in another class

```
public void GetDataFromBase(){
    RecentMethods.AllminersFromBase(firebaseModel, new Callbacks.GetMinerFromBase() {
        @Override
        public void GetMinerFromBase(ArrayList<Miner> minersFromBase) {
            listAdapterMiner.addAll(minersFromBase);
        }
    });
}
```

During the launch of the application, I get the following error

Nullpointerexception in 211 lines of the RecendMethods class

In this stroke

```
 miner.setInHour(snap.child("AllMiners").getValue(Long.class));
```

Nullpointerexception in 211 lines of the RecendMethods class

```
2021-08-30 14:01:23.628 27628-27628/com.egormoroz.schooly E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.egormoroz.schooly, PID: 27628
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.egormoroz.schooly.RecentMethods$8.onDataChange(RecentMethods.java:211)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

Comment: According to your screenshow, `AllMiners` has 3 numeric values in it. Yet in your code, you treat it as a single value and try to convert it to a `Long`: `snap.child("AllMiners").getValue(Long.class)` - is that supposed to work?

Comment: The fact is that I sent these variables with the type Long to the database

Comment: @AlexMamo a couple of days ago, you helped out my friend with a question about the database, please help me, with love

Comment: @Yes, but `AllMiners` in your database is not a `Long`. It is an array of objects, each of which contain 3 values with distinctive names. I don't see you use these names in the code anywhere.

Comment: @f1sh I don't work with databases for a long time, maybe I don't fully understand you, but what are you talking about using this ? I have a problem with getting

Comment: @f1sh I think I understood you about the numbers of my objects, yes(0,1,2,3...)

Comment: @f1sh  if I remove these 3 lines where do I use getValue(Long.class), then for iterates through all the objects from the branch, but since it did not receive data about the object itself due to the absence of these 3 lines, it turns out an empty recycler view

Comment: why are you not using `setMinerPrice(snap.child("minerPrice")`? Shouldn't the names "inHour", "minerImage" and "minerPrice" appear somewhere in the code?

Comment: f1sh I'll try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, please change the following lines of code:

```
miner.setInHour(snap.child("AllMiners").getValue(Long.class));
miner.setMinerPrice(snap.child("AllMiners").getValue(Long.class));
miner.setMinerImage(snap.child("AllMiners").getValue(Long.class));
```

To:

```
miner.setInHour(snap.child("inHour").getValue(Long.class));
miner.setMinerPrice(snap.child("minerImage").getValue(Long.class));
miner.setMinerImage(snap.child("minerPrice").getValue(Long.class));
```

This is because the children in your DataSnapshot object are "inHour", "minerImage" and "minerPrice" and **not** "AllMiners".

Comment: I checked and I get the data as it should, but there is a problem with the output in the recycler view, you can tell me or give a small example

Comment: Good to hear that you are able to get the data now. However, "there is a problem with the output" doesn't provide enough information to help. So I recommend you post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.